# why are the inherit css properties lost?

Tags: css

demo url: http://linjuming.pydra.org/zc_up/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=1_2
I am using oocss css framework in my site. A strange question comes out.

```
.complex .tl, .complex .tr {
  height: 32000px;
  margin-bottom: -32000px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

These code is from stylesheet_010_oocss.css.
But not the same inherited by two place. why this happend?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties of **Hight** and **Width** in `.complex .tl, .complex .tr` rules are lost in `<div class="sort_line s_box_sort_line complex"> ... </div>` cause it properties are re-rules in your css in lowest posisition. Check this out:

```
/*in LINE 85 */
.complex .tl, .complex .tr {
    height: 32000px;
    margin-bottom: -32000px;
    width: 10px;
}

/*in LINE 1696 */    
.r_box_2 .tl, .r_box_2 .tr, .r_box_2 .bl, .r_box_2 .br {
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
}

/*in LINE 2116 */
.s_box_sort_line .tl {
    background-position: -320px -320px;
    height: 32000px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

We are know css codes are rendered from top to bottom. That's why the code that will be used is the most recent code (lowest position).

Comment: got it, i setted firebug only showing the applied rules,that is why can not see the two other properties with line cross off. Thank you very much